# Logs in Flask unittests print out dot after newline

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging

I have a dead simple Flask application :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return("Hello World!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

along with `__main__.py` file:

```
from .core import app

import src.core

app.run()
```

and i added a test:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import logging as log

import src.core

class runTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        src.core.app.testing = True
        self.client = src.core.app.test_client()

    def test_hello_world(self):
        response = self.client.get("/")
        log.warning(f"resp: {response.data}")
        self.assertEqual(b"Hello World!",response.data)
```

overall tree structure looked like:

```
➜  apptest tree -L 2
.
├── src
│   ├── core.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── __pycache__
└── tests
    ├── __pycache__
    └── test.py

4 directories, 3 files
➜  apptest
```

When i run the tests, i got unexpected output:

```
➜  apptest python -m unittest tests.test
WARNING:root:resp: b'Hello World!'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.011s

OK
➜  apptest
```

There is this random dot after newline of the log. I tried out modifying test.py to check it out:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import logging as log

import src.core

class runTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        src.core.app.testing = True
        self.client = src.core.app.test_client()

    def test_hello_world(self):
        response = self.client.get("/")
        log.warning(f"resp: {response.data}")
        log.warning("2nd log")
        self.assertEqual(b"Hello World!",response.data)

    def test_hello_world_2(self):
        log.warning("3rd log")
        log.warning("4th log")
        self.assertEqual("Hello World!",self.teststring)
```

And the output:

```
➜  apptest python -m unittest tests.test
WARNING:root:resp: b'Hello World!'
WARNING:root:2nd log
.WARNING:root:3rd log
WARNING:root:4th log
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.011s

OK
➜  apptest
```

And it appears that last log of every function is printing `\n.` instead of just `\n` , if my thinking is right.

What is causing this, and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Those dots represent a test that has run. The more tests the more dots. Usually they would be on the same line but It looks like they are getting pushed around by your logging output.

Comment: What could be the reason for that? Logging configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem so I did a little test.
If my test hasn't any output, the unittest output will prints out few dots according to the number of unittest functions.
When I have three functions the output format looks like:

`...`

`----------------------------------------------------------------------`

`Ran 3 tests in 0.002s`

`OK`

It seems like unittest prints out one dot a time in ONE LINE after certain test has been done.